# JavaScript - Find a word string out of strings in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to find a word from consecutive strings inside a two dimensional array.

For example:

```
array = [[0,'r',0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,'a',0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,'l',0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,'e',0,0,0,0,0]];
```

I want to make a function that will return true if the word 'apple' is inside this array vertically. Strings need to be consecutive.

Or:

```
array1 = [[0,'e',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'l',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'a',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'q',0,0,0,0,0]];
```

It should work from top to bottom and from bottom to top.

This should return false since there are no consecutive letters:

```
array2 = [[0,'e',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'l',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'a',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'q',0,0,0,0,0]];
```

Can you help please?

Comment: What is your solution that you need help on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that does exactly what you need:

```js
let array1 = [
    [0,'r',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'a',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'l',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'e',0,0,0,0,0]
];

let array2 = [
    [0,'r',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'e',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'l',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,'a',0,0,0,0,0]
];

function includesWordVertically(matrix, word) {

    for (let j = 0 ; j < matrix[0].length ; j++) {

        let verticalWord = '';

        for (let i = 0 ; i < matrix.length ; i++) {
            verticalWord += matrix[i][j];
        }

        if ((verticalWord.includes(word)) ||
            (verticalWord.split('').reverse().join('').includes(word)))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}

console.log(includesWordVertically(array1, 'apple'));
// true
console.log(includesWordVertically(array2, 'apple'));
// true
```

Note that this function does not do the necessary checks (e.g. matrix not empty, all rows have the same length, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I would combine a single string from all characters in one vertical column, and also add another set of same characters, so if the word Apple is divided, you will fins it is a string. After adding all characters twice, you will get a string like 'leappleapp' and you will find an apple there

Answer (score 1):

Returns true Only if found in a straight column.

```js
var array1 = [[0,'a',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'p',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'l',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'e',0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,'q',0,0,0,0,0]];

function isVertically(array, word) {
    var string = "";
    var index = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = array[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            var element = line[j];
            if(typeof element == "string") {
                if(index < 0)
                    index = j;
                if(j === index)
                    string += element;
            } 
        }
    }
 return string == word;
}

isVertically(array1, "apple")
```